# Protect against firefox tamper data

Tags: php, javascript, post, canvas

I was working on a simple javascript canvas pong game with a high score list, and I was wondering if there was any way I could get the score into a database without using the POST or GET method, because the high score list has already been messed up by people using the firefox tamper data plugin. 
Thanks

Comment: Any method will be subject to tampering. This is a complex issue. See for example [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947/74448#74448) and [What are the best practices for making online high score lists in JavaScript based games?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8670612)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a blog post that tackles this subject. It talks more about using flash instead of javascript, but the idea is the same:

> http://spalatnik.com/blog/2012/02/20/securing-php-flash-communication/

Note: I wrote that article. Shameless plug.

Edit: Fixed link

Comment: The OP talks about plain JS, not Flash.

Comment: @Bergi: That's irrelevant to this question. He's talking about preventing data tampering. Which language/platform you choose to describe the problem/solutions don't matter for this type of question. Unless you want specific coded answers..

Comment: link is not working, please update it or write full answer here.

Comment: Will update later today

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.